# Enabling Multilingual/Localization in SharePoint Framework Client Side Webparts

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, localization, multilingual

How to do Multilingual/Localization support in SharePoint Framework Client Side Webparts?

Answer (score 0):

Check the below steps for adding multiple language in SharePoint Framework(SPFx) webparts:

1. Within "loc" folder you will see a file named "mystrings.d.ts". At first add property here like below:

```
declare interface ITestWebPartStrings {
  WebpartTitle: string;
}
```

2. There is a file for english language named "en-us.js". If you want to 
   add another language you have to create another file. For example if 
   you want to add Norwegian language then you have to create "nb-NO.js" file.
3. After that add the property in "nb-NO.js" file for Norwegian language.
   And for english language add property within "en-us.js" file as like below:

```
define([], function() {
    return {
        "WebpartTitle": "YourTitle",
    }
});
```

4. Now you have to import in your file.

```
import * as strings from 'TestWebPartStrings';
```

5. Now you can show "WebpartTitle" using "strings.WebpartTitle". This is the process to add multiple language.

```
let wpTitle = strings.WebpartTitle;
```

References:
1. nopvalley.com: [Enabling Multilingual/Localization in SharePoint](https://www.nopvalley.com/enabling-multilingual-in-sharepoint-framework-client-side-webparts) 
2. From Microsoft documentation: [Localize SharePoint Framework client-side web parts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/localize-web-parts)

---

*If the answer is helpful, please upvote.*